# Moodle edit navigation bar

Tags: moodle, navigationbar

Good day, I'm trying to add a new link which is named **Upload** below *"Export"* but I'm failing to do so. Could any of you help on what I'm trying to achieve. I'm still new to Moodle development, I have a lot of things to learn first.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Moodle are you using? 
In 2.6 take a look at the question_extend_settings_navigation method in lib/questionlib.php

Comment: This might help, if I have time I'll create some code for you https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins#Adding_an_element_to_the_settings_menu

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response @IamFraz, I will look onto that and skim that. I apologize for the late response.

Comment: And also @RussellEngland thanks! I will go through the link you provided. I apologize for the late response.

Comment: @IamFraz I've managed to add a new link, thanks a lot! But the link is something like this [[Upload]]. It has [[ ]] even though I didn't provide brackets.

Comment: yowza, I think you should add a key in a language.php file... Check get_string [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/String_API) .
What @RussellEngland suggests is more neat and clean. Russel, I'm wondering if it's possible from a module override a node added by another module. Is It?

Comment: I will go over what you instructed, thanks! I'm trying to do what @RussellEngland suggested, I still have difficulties in it but I have little progress so far.

Comment: @RussellEngland good day sir, I managed to do what is instructed on what you gave but there are brackets surrounding upload. Why is this happening? Albeit I didn't declared brackets.
[[Upload]]